# Design Patterns: Factory vs Factory method vs Abstract Factory

Tags: java, design-patterns, language-agnostic, factory, factory-method

I was reading design patterns from a website

There I read about Factory, Factory method and Abstract factory but they are so confusing, am not clear on the definition. According to definitions

> Factory - Creates objects without exposing the instantiation logic to the client and Refers to the newly created object through a common interface. *Is a simplified version of Factory Method*
>
> Factory Method - Defines an interface for creating objects, but let subclasses to decide which class to instantiate and Refers to the newly created object through a common interface.
>
> Abstract Factory - Offers the interface for creating a family of related objects, without explicitly specifying their classes.

I also looked the other stackoverflow threads regarding Abstract Factory vs Factory Method but the UML diagrams drawn there make my understanding even worse.

Can anyone please tell me

1. How are these three patterns different from each other?
2. When to use which?
3. And also if possible, any java examples related to these patterns?

Comment: While I was looking for answers to roughly the same question as the O.P., I found this article: [From No Factory to Factory Method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492900/From-No-Factory-to-Factory-Method).  It provides the insight by following the evolution of a sample project (factory method mentioned in the title is one of the evolutionary steps).

Comment: I stumbled over this after reading the following article, which describes the problem quite well: ["Codeproject- Factory methode vs. abstract factory](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/716413/factory-method-pattern-vs-abstract-factory-pattern).

Answer (score 372):

All three Factory types do the same thing: They are a "smart constructor".

Let's say you want to be able to create two kinds of Fruit: Apple and Orange.

#### Factory

Factory is "fixed", in that you have just one implementation with no subclassing. In this case, you will have a class like this:

```
class FruitFactory {

  public Apple makeApple() {
    // Code for creating an Apple here.
  }

  public Orange makeOrange() {
    // Code for creating an orange here.
  }

}
```

Use case: Constructing an Apple or an Orange is a bit too complex to handle in the constructor for either.

#### Factory Method

Factory method is generally used when you have some generic processing in a class, but want to vary which kind of fruit you actually use. So:

```
abstract class FruitPicker {

  protected abstract Fruit makeFruit();

  public void pickFruit() {
    private final Fruit f = makeFruit(); // The fruit we will work on..
    <bla bla bla>
  }
}
```

...then you can reuse the common functionality in `FruitPicker.pickFruit()` by implementing a factory method in subclasses:

```
class OrangePicker extends FruitPicker {

  @Override
  protected Fruit makeFruit() {
    return new Orange();
  }
}
```

#### Abstract Factory

Abstract factory is normally used for things like dependency injection/strategy, when you want to be able to create a whole family of objects that need to be of "the same kind", and have some common base classes. Here's a vaguely fruit-related example. The use case here is that we want to make sure that we don't accidentally use an OrangePicker on an Apple. As long as we get our Fruit and Picker from the same factory, they will match.

```
interface PlantFactory {
  
  Plant makePlant();

  Picker makePicker(); 

}

public class AppleFactory implements PlantFactory {
  Plant makePlant() {
    return new Apple();
  }

  Picker makePicker() {
    return new ApplePicker();
  }
}

public class OrangeFactory implements PlantFactory {
  Plant makePlant() {
    return new Orange();
  }

  Picker makePicker() {
    return new OrangePicker();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the answer that is most alike to my understanding of these patterns. Adding examples of calling code (Client) would also help? Question that bothers me a lot is: can we say that Abstract Factory Pattern is just Factory extended with Factory Method Pattern (if this is true, I'm clear on this topic)?

Comment: @AndréAndrade

How to invoke the **Factory Method** ? A small code samle pls :)

That will clear my doubt on its usage

Comment: The abstract factory example is not quite right. You could have easily seperated out the `makePlant` and `makePicker` functions into two seperate classes. The point is not to have multiple `makeXYZ` functions inside the same class. What it actually does is allow you to select between two different implementations of something. None of the answers really explain this well, so I will add something.

Comment: What you are missing is something which returns an `AppleFactory` or a `OrangeFactory`.

Comment: @ArnabDutta
Client code to invoke factory method can be found in this page [oodesign-com-factory-method-pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern)

Answer (score 49):

Based this images from [Design Patterns in C#, 2nd Edition by Vaskaran Sarcar](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484236406) book:

> **1. Simple Factory Pattern**

Creates objects without exposing the instantiation logic to the client.

```
SimpleFactory simpleFactory = new SimpleFactory();
IAnimal dog = simpleFactory.CreateDog(); // Create dog
IAnimal tiger = simpleFactory.CreateTiger(); // Create tiger
```

[image]

> **2. Factory Method Pattern**

Defines an interface for creating objects, but let subclasses to decide which class to instantiate.

```
AnimalFactory dogFactory = new DogFactory(); 
IAnimal dog = dogFactory.CreateAnimal(); // Create dog

AnimalFactory tigerFactory = new TigerFactory();
IAnimal tiger = tigerFactory.CreateAnimal(); // Create tiger
```

[image]

> **3. Abstract Factory pattern** (factory of factories)

Abstract Factory offers the interface for creating a family of related objects, without explicitly specifying their classes

```
IAnimalFactory petAnimalFactory = FactoryProvider.GetAnimalFactory("pet");
IDog dog = petAnimalFactory.GetDog(); // Create pet dog
ITiger tiger = petAnimalFactory.GetTiger();  // Create pet tiger

IAnimalFactory wildAnimalFactory = FactoryProvider.GetAnimalFactory("wild");
IDog dog = wildAnimalFactory .GetDog(); // Create wild dog
ITiger tiger = wildAnimalFactory .GetTiger();  // Create wild tiger
```

[image]

Comment: 100% clarity. Underrated answer

Comment: This one is actually confusing to me. Why not create an abstract `AnimalFactory` in a way which you can use it like this: `IAnimal animal = AnimalFactory.create("dog");`. Why do I need a separate factory for each type and thus "factory of factories"? What is gained by this?

Comment: @Nom1fan If we have a simple system, we can write as simple as that, but when the system becomes complex, the factory of factories helps a lot to control the complexity.

Answer (score 31):

***Q1. How are these three patterns different from each other?***

Definition from Wikipedia/Gang of Four ( Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software book)

> *Factory:* Creates objects without exposing the instantiation logic to the client.

> *[Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):* Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation it uses to subclasses." (Gang Of Four)

> *Abstract Factory:* Provides an interface for creating families of related objects without specifying their concrete classes.

AbstractFactory pattern uses composition to delegate responsibility of creating object to another class

*Factory method* design pattern uses inheritance and uses derived class for creation of objects

***Q2. When to use which?***

*Factory:* Client just need a class and don't bother about implementer

*Factory Method:* Client doesn't know what concrete classes it will be required to create the object

*AbstactFactory:*  When your system has to create multiple families of products without exposing the implementation details.

Abstract Factory classes are often implemented with Factory Method.

***Q3. And also if possible, any java examples related to these patterns?***

**Problem statement:** Create a Factory of Games by using Factory Methods, which defines the game interface.

Code snippet:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;


/* Product interface as per UML diagram */
interface Game{
    /* createGame is a complex method, which executes a sequence of game steps */
    public void createGame();
}

/* ConcreteProduct implementation as per UML diagram */
class Chess implements Game{
    public Chess(){
        
    }
    public void createGame(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Create Chess game");
        System.out.println("Opponents:2");
        System.out.println("Define 64 blocks");
        System.out.println("Place 16 pieces for White opponent");
        System.out.println("Place 16 pieces for Black opponent");
        System.out.println("Start Chess game");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
}
class Checkers implements Game{
    public Checkers(){
       
    }
    public void createGame(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Create Checkers game");
        System.out.println("Opponents:2 or 3 or 4 or 6");
        System.out.println("For each opponent, place 10 coins");
        System.out.println("Start Checkers game");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
}
class Ludo implements Game{
    public Ludo(){
        
    }
    public void createGame(){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Create Ludo game");
        System.out.println("Opponents:2 or 3 or 4");
        System.out.println("For each opponent, place 4 coins");
        System.out.println("Create two dices with numbers from 1-6");
        System.out.println("Start Ludo game");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
}

/* Creator interface as per UML diagram */
interface IGameFactory {
    public Game getGame(String gameName);
}

/* ConcreteCreator implementation as per UML diagram */
class GameFactory implements IGameFactory {
        
     HashMap<String,Game> games = new HashMap<String,Game>();
    /*  
        Since Game Creation is complex process, we don't want to create game using new operator every time.
        Instead we create Game only once and store it in Factory. When client request a specific game, 
        Game object is returned from Factory instead of creating new Game on the fly, which is time consuming
    */
    
    public GameFactory(){
        
        games.put(Chess.class.getName(),new Chess());
        games.put(Checkers.class.getName(),new Checkers());
        games.put(Ludo.class.getName(),new Ludo());        
    }
    public Game getGame(String gameName){
        return games.get(gameName);
    }
}

public class NonStaticFactoryDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        if ( args.length < 1){
            System.out.println("Usage: java FactoryDemo gameName");
            return;
        }
     
        GameFactory factory = new GameFactory();
        Game game = factory.getGame(args[0]);
        if ( game != null ){                    
            game.createGame();
            System.out.println("Game="+game.getClass().getName());
        }else{
            System.out.println(args[0]+  " Game does not exists in factory");
        }           
    }
}
```

output:

```
java NonStaticFactoryDemo Chess
---------------------------------------
Create Chess game
Opponents:2
Define 64 blocks
Place 16 pieces for White opponent
Place 16 pieces for Black opponent
Start Chess game
---------------------------------------
Game=Chess
```

This example shows a `Factory` class by implementing a `FactoryMethod`.

1. `Game` is the interface for all type of games. It defines complex method: `createGame()`
2. `Chess, Ludo, Checkers` are different variants of games, which provide implementation to `createGame()`
3. `public Game getGame(String gameName)` is `FactoryMethod` in `IGameFactory` class
4. `GameFactory` pre-creates different type of games in constructor. It implements `IGameFactory` factory method.
5. game Name is passed as command line argument to `NotStaticFactoryDemo`
6. `getGame` in `GameFactory` accepts a game name and returns corresponding `Game` object.

Comment: For Factory Method, shouldn't it be define a superclass?

Answer (score 22):

**Factory** - Separate Factory class to create complex object.

Ex: FruitFactory class to create object of Fruit

```
class FruitFactory{

public static Fruit getFruit(){...}

}
```

**Factory Method** - Instead of whole separate class for factory, just add one method in that class itself as a factory.

Ex:

```
Calendar.getInstance() (Java's Calendar)
```

**Abstract Factory** - Factory of Factories

Ex: Lets say we want to build factory for computer parts. So there are several types of computers like Laptop, Desktop, Server.

So for each compter type we need factory. So we create one highlevel factory of factories like below

```
ComputerTypeAbstractFactory.getComputerPartFactory(String computerType) ---> This will return PartFactory which can be one of these ServerPartFactory, LaptopPartFactory, DesktopPartFactory.
```

Now these 3 itself are again factories. (You will be dealing with PartFactory itself, but under the hood, there will be separate implementation based on what you provided in abstract factory)

```
  Interface-> PartFactory. getComputerPart(String s), 
Implementations -> ServerPartFactory, LaptopPartFactory, DesktopPartFactory.

Usage:
new ComputerTypeAbstractFactory().getFactory(“Laptop”).getComputerPart(“RAM”)
```

EDIT: edited to provide exact interfaces for Abstract Factory as per the objections in comments.

Comment: The idea behind the `ComputerFactory` would be that you have a common creation interface (`getScreen(); getKeyboard(); getDiskdrive(); ...`), not an interface per computer type as you suggest.  You can smell a design issue if you use the same word twice in the same statement: *Laptop*Factory.get*Laptop*Part().

Comment: No no no, don't go exactly on code itself. It was just an anology for understanding. If you want exact example with interfaces, here it is.       

 Objects: 

Interface -> ComputerPart, 
Implementation -> RAM, HDD, Processor

Factory: 

Interface-> PartFactory. getComputerPart(String s), 
Implementations -> ServerPartFactory, LaptopPartFactory, DesktopPartFactory.

Abstract Factory: ComputerType.getPartFactory(“String s”)


Usage: new ComputerType().getFactory(“Laptop”).getComputerPart(“RAM”)

Comment: I have updated answer to take care of your concern. Actually abstract factory is nothing but factoy of factory only. I gave earlier example just for reference (Assuming readers will take care of interfaces while actual implementation). Still thanks for notifying. Its always good to improve. :)

Comment: No `abstract Factory` is not a factory of factory... It's an `abstract class` or an `interface` able to create object that will be implemented/extended with different concrete factories. See the accepted answer for code details. And please remove or edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: I like the explanation of factory method, which is concise enough to unveil why it is so named. In this pattern, the factory is the method, NOT the class who is generally not a helper utility grouping instantiation methods but meaningful on its own. Other more elaborate answers unfortunately missed this point.

Comment: Your example for Factory Method is wrong and does the common mistake of confusing the design pattern with simple static factory methods. See Joshua Bloch's Effective Java: _"Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors"_, I quote: "_Note that a static factory method is not the same as the Factory Method pattern from Design Patterns_".

Answer (score 15):

For this answer, I refer to the "Gang of Four" book.

There are **no** "Factory" nor "Simple Factory" nor "Virtual Factory" definitions in the book. **Usually** when people are talking about "Factory" pattern they may be talking about **something that creates a particular object of a class** (but not the "builder" pattern); they **may or may not** refer to the "Factory Method" or "Abstract Factory" patterns. Anyone can implement "Factory" as he won't because it's not a formal term (bear in mind that some people\companies\communities can have their own vocabulary).

The book **only** contains definitions for "Abstract Factory" and "Factory Method".

Here are definitions from the book and a short explanation of why both can be so confusing. I omit code examples because you can find them in other answers:

**Factory Method (GOF)**: Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

**Abstract Factory (GOF)**: Provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes.

**Source of Confusion**: Often, one can call a class that used in "Factory Method" pattern as "Factory". This class is abstract by definition. That's why it easy to call this class "Abstract Factory". But it's just the name of the class; you shouldn't confuse it with "Abstract Factory" pattern (class name != pattern name). The "Abstract Factory" pattern is different - it does **not** use an abstract class; it defines an interface (not necessarily a programming language interface) for creating parts of a bigger object or objects that are related to each other or must be created in a particular way.

Comment: This is what we need to look at; GOF is the defacto standard for design patterns. Rest all terms, vocabulary are all just there.

Answer (score 12):

Every design pattern strives to help ensure that written, working code is not touched. We all know that once we touch working code, there are defects in existing working flows, and a lot more testing needs to get done to ensure that we did not break anything.

A factory pattern creates objects based on input criteria, thus ensuring that you dont need to write code like:

```
 if (this) {
     create this kind of object 
 } else { 
     that kind of object 
 }
```

A good example of this is a travel website. A travel website can only provide travel (flight, train, bus) or / and provide hotels or / and provide tourist attraction packages. Now, when a user selects next, the website needs to decide what objects it needs to create. Should it only create the travel or hotel object too.

Now, if you envision adding another website to your portfolio, and you believe that the same core be used, for example, a carpooling website, which now searches for cab's and makes payments online, you can use a abstract factory at your core. This way you can just snap in one more factory of cabs and carpools.

Both factories have nothing to do with each other, so it's a good design to keep them in different factories.

Hope this is clear now. Study the website again keeping this example in mind, hopefully it will help. And I really hope I have represented the patterns correctly :).

Answer (score 2):

```
AbstractProductA, A1 and A2 both implementing the AbstractProductA
AbstractProductB, B1 and B2 both implementing the AbstractProductB

interface Factory {
    AbstractProductA getProductA(); //Factory Method - generate A1/A2
}
```

Using Factory Method, user can able to create A1 or A2 of AbstractProductA.

```
interface AbstractFactory {
    AbstractProductA getProductA(); //Factory Method
    AbstractProductB getProductB(); //Factory Method
}
```

But Abstract Factory having more than 1 factory method ( ex: 2 factory methods), using those factory methods it will create the set of objects/ related objects.
Using Abstract Factory, user can able to create A1, B1 objects of AbstractProductA, AbstractProductB

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has quoted the original book [*Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEIBB8), which gives the answer in the first two paragraphs of the section “Discussion of Creational Patterns” (emphasis mine):

> There are two common ways to parameterize a system by the classes of objects it creates. One way is to **subclass** the class that creates the objects; this corresponds to using the Factory Method (107) pattern. The main drawback of this approach is that it can require a new subclass just to change the class of the product. Such changes can cascade. For example, when the product creator is itself created by a factory method, then you have to override its creator as well.
>
> The other way to parameterize a system relies more on object **composition**: Define an object that’s responsible for knowing the class of the product objects, and make it a parameter of the system. This is a key aspect of the Abstract Factory (87), Builder (97), and Prototype (117) patterns. All three involve creating a new “factory object” whose responsibility is to create product objects. Abstract Factory has the factory object producing objects of several classes. Builder has the factory object building a complex product incrementally using a correspondingly complex protocol. Prototype has the factory object building a product by copying a prototype object. In this case, the factory object and the prototype are the same object, because the prototype is responsible for returning the product.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers really explain the Abstract Factory particularly well - probably because the concept is abstract and this is less frequently used in practice.

An easy to understand example arrises from considering the following situation.

You have a system, which interfaces with another system. I will use the example given in Design Patterns Explained by Shalloway and Trott, P194, because this situation is so rare I can't think of a better one. In their book, they give the example of having different combinations of local hardware resources. They use, as examples:

- System with high resoltion display and print driver
- System with low resolution display and print driver

There are 2 options for one variable thing (print driver, display driver), and 2 options for the other variable thing (high resolution, low resolution). We want to couple these together in such a way that we have a `HighResolutionFactory` and a `LowResolutionFactory` which produce for us both a print driver and display driver of the correct type.

This then is the Abstract Factory pattern:

```
class ResourceFactory
{
    virtual AbstractPrintDriver getPrintDriver() = 0;

    virtual AbstractDisplayDriver getDisplayDriver() = 0;
};

class LowResFactory : public ResourceFactory
{
    AbstractPrintDriver getPrintDriver() override
    {
        return LowResPrintDriver;
    }

    AbstractDisplayDriver getDisplayDriver() override
    {
        return LowResDisplayDriver;
    }
};

class HighResFactory : public ResourceFactory
{
    AbstractPrintDriver getPrintDriver() override
    {
        return HighResPrintDriver;
    }

    AbstractDisplayDriver getDisplayDriver() override
    {
        return HighResDisplayDriver;
    }
};
```

I won't detail both the print driver and display driver hierachies, just one will suffice to demonstrate.

```
class AbstractDisplayDriver
{
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class HighResDisplayDriver : public AbstractDisplayDriver
{
    void draw() override
    {
        // do hardware accelerated high res drawing
    }
};

class LowResDisplayDriver : public AbstractDisplayDriver
{
    void draw() override
    {
        // do software drawing, low resolution
    }
};
```

Why it works:

We could have solved this problem with a bunch of `if` statements:

```
const resource_type = LOW_RESOLUTION;

if(resource_type == LOW_RESOLUTION)
{
    drawLowResolution();
    printLowResolution();
}
else if(resource_type == HIGH_RESOLUTION)
{
    drawHighResolution();
    printHighResolution();
}
```

Instead of this we now can do:

```
    auto factory = HighResFactory;
    auto printDriver = factory.getPrintDriver();
    printDriver.print();
    auto displayDriver = factory.getDisplayDriver();
    displayDriver.draw();
```

Essentially - We have abstracted away the runtime logic into the v-table for our classes.

My opinion on this pattern is that it isn't actually very useful. It couples together some things which need not be coupled together. The point of design patterns is usally to reduce coupling, not increase it, therefore in some ways this pattern is really an anti-pattern, but it might be useful in some contexts.

If you get to a stage where you are seriously considering implementing this, you might consider some alternative designs. Perhaps you could write a factory which returns factories, which themselves return the objects you eventually want. I imagine this would be more flexible, and would not have the same coupling issues.

Addendum: The example from Gang of Four is similarly coupled. They have a `MotifFactory` and a `PMFactory`. These then produce `PMWindow`, `PMScrollBar` and `MotifWindow`, `MotifScrollBar` respectively. This is a somewhat dated text now and so it might be hard to understand the context. I recall reading this chapter and the I understood little from the example beyond having two implementations of a factory base class which return different families of objects.