# Why is it a good practice to define a variable with a supertype?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

"Introduction to Java programming", says:

> To enable generic programming,
>   it is a good practice to define a variable with a supertype, which can accept a value of any subtype.

Code example:

```
 Object myObject = new Circle();

... // Some lines of code

System.out.println("The circle diameter is " +
((Circle)myObject) .getDiameter());

... // Some lines of code
```

Why not define myObject as a Circle type in the first place?

Comment: Example you provided may be a good practice in a very few cases. For me, it is awful.

Comment: Introduction to Java programming sounds like a horribly bad book, or the OP understood something wrong.

Comment: In most cases, the simplest and clearest code is best.  It is likely that the example they provide is not a good one.

Comment: if I recall that book is over 10 years old...

Comment: Please provide an example that makes some sense. In this example, I can't see what difference does defining myObject as Object type, rather than as Cirlce, make?

Comment: @Saud The only difference is you need an extra casting to `Circle`. So it provides no advantage at all. (In this example)

Comment: @Manu . Another example of this practice (making no sense to me):
`Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();`
Then he uses this set to store some strings and display them using an iterator. Declaring set as Set<String> rather than HashSet<String>, I think he is simply making the code prone to more errors.

Comment: @Saud That's a different case. `Set` is a well defined interface, and it usually doesn't matter what the actual runtime class being used is. I don't see how it would be prone to errors, unless someone makes assumptions about the concrete class being used (which would be an error on that developer's part).

Comment: @Kayaman agreed. But you do have to be more cautious; like you said, one might erroneously assume Set as a concrete class.

Comment: @Saud No, that's not what I meant at all. Any half-decent Java programmer knows that `Set` is an interface, if not, he shouldn't be touching code at all. My example was about a developer thinking that `Set` is a `HashSet`, when there's no guarantees about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets make a simple Example with a class `Fruit`

```
public class Fruit {
   public void eat() {
       //some code
   }
}
```

And two other classes

```
public class Banana extends Fruit{

}
//
public class Apple extends Fruit{

}
```

Now let´s create a Person

```
public class Person {
    public void eat(Fruit f) {
        f.eat();
    } 
}
```

Let´s use this now

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person();
    // We are creating a random Fruit, and pass it to the person to eat.
    // We can´t be more specific here and don´t need to be more specific
    Fruit f = getRandomFruit();
    p.eat(f);
}

public static Fruit getRandomFruit() {
    if(new Random().nextInt(2) == 0) {
        return new Banana();
    } else {
        return new Apple();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in this case, this example does more harm than good. To do any `Circle` or `Shape` related operations you will need to cast your current object. Other than adding potential overhead, this could lead to issues such as incompatible types.

Doing generic programming is usually recommended since it allows your code to be flexible. **Unlike the example you have posted however, it is recommended only when done right. Creating everything as an object will almost always do more harm than good**.

Taking the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) as an example, if you where to have a method which returns an `ArrayList<String>` as a result: `public ArrayList<String> foo()`, then, you are bound to that particular type. If you want a linked list, you will probably need to write some sort of converter which creates a `LinkedList<String>` from an `ArrayList<String>`.

On the other hand, if you use the generic interface instead, your method would become something like so: `public List<String> foo()`. This will allow who ever consumes `foo` to be able to create any one of the data structures which implement the `List` interface without the need of going through hoops.

EDIT: As per your comment, most of the time it does not help. As I mentioned in my answer it does more harm than good. One of the instances where working with objects makes sense is the [`readObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) method provided by the `ObjectInputStream`. This method is used when you are reading a custom object, which the `ObjectInputStream` does not know about. Since in Java everything extends the `Object` class, this method yields an object. Even then, every illustration I have seen of this method they eventually cast it to something else.

Comment: **How does defining myObject as Object type help in generic programming?** Can you please cite a case where doing this actualy makes sense..

Comment: @Saud: As I and others have mentioned, declared something as `Object` does more harm than good. The `List` example provided should yield something which is more practical. I've updated my answer with a situation in which the Java API yields an `Object`, but even then, the object will be eventually cast to something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify the example a little bit, by deriving `Circle`, `Square` , `RectAngle` from `Shape` instead of Object, it will make good sense. `Shape` can have methods like `getArea()` and attributes like height and width, which can be overridden by derived classes.

```
Shape circle = new Circle();
Shape rectangle = new Rectagle();
```

In real life examples, it is better to use Base generic types for derived classes so that an implementation can change at run time.

If you are looking for object creation, use simple [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

If you are looking to change the behaviour of the object at run time, use [Strategy_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

If you are working on multiple strategies for feature, strategy can replaced dynamically by changing base to new derived strategy.

Have a look at below examples:

[Design Patterns: Factory vs Factory method vs Abstract Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029261/design-patterns-factory-vs-factory-method-vs-abstract-factory/35851402#35851402)

[Real World Example of the Strategy Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370258/real-world-example-of-the-strategy-pattern/35180265#35180265)