# Static factory and factory design patterns

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern, static-factory

Are `static` factory and **factory design patterns** the same?

I heard that the static factory concepts are used in *Spring framework*.

Google results show more about factory method design pattern when I looked up **"static factory design pattern"**. If they are not the same, is the static factory design pattern used only for dependency injection?

Comment: Factory, FactoryMethod and AbstractFactory patterns are present. No pattern with name StaticFactory. Do you mean static Factory = Factory with static method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029261/design-patterns-factory-vs-factory-method-vs-abstract-factory/