# "Factory Method Design Pattern" in context of Java interfaces?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, factory-method

I am a beginner in Java and the book that I use to learn it seems to have cryptic examples and sentences that completely confuse me.

I understand what interfaces are and how/where to apply the concept in real world. But what are Factory Methods? The term "factory method" is ambiguous (JavaScript has a different meaning for that) so I am providing the snippet that the book has, in order to make my question clear. Here is the code:

```
interface Service {
    void method1();
    void method2();
}

interface ServiceFactory {
    Service getService();
}
```

The `Service` interface is just a normal interface. `ServiceFactory` interface looks like a normal interface but it is a "Factory Method". What's that? What does it solve and why I should use them?

Comment: Strictly, `ServiceFactory` is a "normal" interface too. A Factory Method needs some kind of implementation (starting with Java 8, this can be a default method in an interface) since it needs to produce (create) an instance of some type (hence the term "factory"). You *can* specify the factory method in an interface, but still you need a concrete Factory class which creates specific types. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design Patterns: Factory vs Factory method vs Abstract Factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029261/design-patterns-factory-vs-factory-method-vs-abstract-factory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "factory method" is a method that constructs an object.

More specifically, the term usually refers to a static method that returns an instance of its declaring class (either a direct instance, or an instance of a subclass). In my experience, there are a few cases where that's particularly commonly done:

- If you need to have multiple different constructors, using factory methods lets you give them appropriate names (whereas calls to different constructors can only be distinguished by the argument-types, which aren't always obvious at a glance).
- If you need to have a few different implementations of a single abstract class that serves as the entry-point, the factory method can instantiate the appropriate subtype.
- If you need any sort of caching logic or shared instances, the factory method can handle that, returning an already-existing instance if appropriate.
- If you need to do some work with side effects, a factory method can be named in such a way that it's more clear what those side effects are.

So, your example doesn't really involve a "factory method" IMHO, but you can cheat a bit and describe `getService()` as one. (Rather, I would just describe `ServiceFactory` as a "factory" at leave it at that.) The benefits of `ServiceFactory.getService()` are the same as those of a factory method, *plus* the usual benefits of having an instance instead of a static method.

Comment: It should always be noted that the Static Factory Method is NOT the same as the GoF Factory Method Pattern. The two are completely different.

Comment: @jaco0646: Ah, you are right. The OP's example does not seem to be an example of either one, though.

Comment: Agreed; the term _factory_ is often used very loosely to describe any creational method. This loose terminology is then conflated with GoF or other terminology, and confusion ensues.

Answer (score 1):

A factory method is simply a method that encaspulate the creation of an object. Instead of using the `new` operator as you normally would for creating an instead of a `Service`, in your example, you're using the factory method on some object.

```
ServiceFactory sf = new ServiceFactoryImpl();
// factory method
Service s = sf.getService();
```

To better illustrate the role of the method, it could be called `createService` instead. Now the method encapsulates the details of the creation of a `Service`, you can provide many flavors of the methods (by overloading), you can have it return different subclasses depending on the context, or parameters passed to the factory method.