# Return a subclass of a subclass

Tags: java

I have an assignment that calculates the area and perimeter of shapes.

The superclass:

```
public abstract class Shape implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1231855623100981927L;

    public abstract boolean draw();
    public abstract String area();
    public abstract String perimeter();
    public abstract String characteristic();
}
```

Rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Rectangle() {}

    public Rectangle(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Square class:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {

    private double x;

    public Square() {}

    public Square(double side) {       
        super(side, side);
        this.x = side;
    }

    public Square square(double side){
        this.x = side;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
 Shape rec = new Rectangle();
```

What I want is when the height and width of a rectangle are equal, it will return the `Square` class instead of the `Rectangle` class. That's all I want.

Comment: Did you try out something by yourself?

Comment: What are you talking about? I already tried.

Comment: @tima haha newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a Rectangle, you can't turn it into a Square or anything like that. You might use a [factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030163/1907186). The factory would be an instance of a class with a method that, for your case, would take a width and a height. When they are equal, it will return a `new Square(x)` and when they are not equal, will return a `new Rectangle(x, y)`. You'd need to move the System.in readLine calls to an application entry point (presumably a `main` method), and the factory method would be called from there.