# Need suggestions in help making a conditional parameter initialize a class with DI, C#, and Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webapi

I am using Unity dependency injection and Web API 2.0.

I have a controller which I am injecting my unit of work:

```
public ProductController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

I then have a method in that controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateProducts(string website)
{ 
   ProductAPI productAPI;
   Enum.TryParse(website, out Website website);

   productAPI = new ProductAPI(_unitOfWork, website);
   productAPI.UpdateProducts();
}
```

The method takes in a parameter website which is a enum. It has 3 different values (website1, website2, website3).

This is the ProductAPI constructor that takes in UOW and the web site enum:

```
public ProductAPI(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Website website)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _website = website;
    _httpClient = CommonAPI.GetHttpClient(website);
}
```

The `CommonAPI` class is a static class that returns the `httpclient` based on the web site.

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient(Website website)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    if (website == Website.1)
    {
        //return httpclient for website 1
    }
    else if (website == Website.2)
    {
        //return httpclient for website 2
    }
    else if (website == Website.3)
    {
        //return httpclient for website 3
    }

    return httpClient;
}
```

The `ProductAPI` class also has calls within its methods that use the UOW but also use the website enum to filter based on the web site value:

```
List<ProductViewModel> products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetProducts(_website.ToString());
```

Is there a better and cleaner way to set this code up based on that web site enum?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? If this is a basically working code you only want to improve I'ld say it should rather go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

With your static method, basically you are using the factory method pattern. It's a common pattern, but if you want more flexibility you could use an abstract factory as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029261/design-patterns-factory-vs-factory-method-vs-abstract-factory).

The caller is defining what kind of website is used to update the products So, placing that logic in the controller makes perfect sense.

In general; there could be some higher level of abstraction but the code seems fine just as it is.

---

But if you want to get your hands dirty: you could abstract the WebClient.

E.g.:

Define a common interface:

```
public interface IYourTypicalHandler{ /*def here */}
```

And implement it:

```
public class Web1Client : IYourTypicalHandler, HttpClient  { /*logic here */ }
public class Web2Client : IYourTypicalHandler, HttpClient  { /*logic here */ }
public class Web3Client : IYourTypicalHandler, HttpClient  { /*logic here */ }
```

Now you have encapsulated and isolated your specific web behavior in different classes. This can be used as implementation strategy for your `ProductAPI`.

First create an interface for it:

```
public interface IProductApi { /* def here */ }
```

The signature of the implementation will be:

```
 public class ProductAPI : IProductApi {
     public ProductAPI(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IYourTypicalHandler)
 }
```

Now you can use the `IYourTypicalHandler`, to invoke the actual call. These modifications split up implementation details and makes the code easier to unit-test, and most likely, easier to use in a DI driven environment.

---

Of course you need to rewire your factory:

```
//note: not bound to http anymore ;-)
public static IYourTypicalHandler GetHttpClient(Website website)
```

---

At this point you don't have access to `_website.ToString()` in:

```
var products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.GetProducts(_website.ToString());
```

which might complicate things, and might be targeted as well. So, it's up to you if it's worth it ;-)

Hope this helps.