# how to implement factory design pattern in c# to draw shapes?

Tags: c#, .net, factory-pattern

I am trying to learn c# and in c# I am trying to implement a factory design pattern to draw basic shapes like circle, rectangle, triangle, etc. I created a `IShape` Interface class. And other three Circle, Rectangle, and Triangle class. I also created a `ShapeFactory` static method. These classes sould be called after from compiler class and draw in another window i.e Output window. Below is the code.

```
//IShape Class
namespace CPaint.Class
{
    public interface IShape
    {
        void Draw();
    }
}

//Cicle Class
namespace CPaint.Class
{
    internal class Circle : IShape
    {
        //public Output outputWindow;
        private float x;

        private float y;
        private Color color;
        private float radius;
        private Graphics graphics;

        public Circle(Color color, float x, float y, float radius)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
            graphics.FillEllipse(brush, x, y, radius, radius);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, radius, radius);
        }
    }
}

//Triangle class
namespace CPaint.Class
{
    internal class Triangle : IShape
    {
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private Color color;
        private float side1;
        private float side2;
        private float side3;

        public Triangle(Color color, float x, float y, float side1, float side2, float side3)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.side1 = side1;
            this.side2 = side2;
            this.side3 = side3;
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
            //will write drawing code here...
        }
    }
}

//Shape Factory Class
namespace CPaint.Class
{
    public class ShapeFactory
    {
        public static IShape GetShape(string shapeType, Color color, float x, float y, float height, float width, float radius, float side1, float side2, float side3)
        {
            if (shapeType == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (shapeType.Equals("circle"))
            {
                return new Circle(color, x, y, radius);
            }
            else if (shapeType.Equals("rectangle"))
            {
                return new Rectangle(color, x, y, height, width); ;
            }
            else if (shapeType.Equals("triangle"))
            {
                return new Triangle(color, x, y, side1, side2, side3);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Compiler Class
if (code[0].Trim().ToLower().Equals("circle"))
{
    try
    {
        int parameter1 = Int32.Parse(code[1]);

        IShape shape = ShapeFactory.GetShape("circle", color, initX, initY, 0, 0, parameter1, 0, 0, 0);
        outputWindow.Show();

        //outputWindow.outputArea.Image=new ShapeFactory.GetShape("circle", color, initX, initY, 0, 0, parameter1, 0, 0, 0);
        //outputWindow.outputArea.Image = shape;

        output = "command executed successfully: parameter is" + parameter1;
        //output = "is numeric ";
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
        output = "\n Parameter Error : Invalid/Insufficient Parameter. \n";
    }
}
```

Here in Compiler class, I want to open output window by `outputWindow.show();` and then draw the shape in window by `outputWindow.OutputArea.Image=...`

I got stuck. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/factory-method-design-pattern-dotnet

Comment: I looked at this  
   IFactory bike = factory.GetVehicle("Bike");
   bike.Drive(20);
in my case I cant draw here, 
     IShape shape = ShapeFactory.GetShape("circle", color, initX, initY, 0, 0, parameter1, 0, 0, 0);
outputWindow.outputArea.Image=shape.Draw(); but it shows error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029261/design-patterns-factory-vs-factory-method-vs-abstract-factory) explains differences between

- Factory,
- Factory Method, and
- Abstract Factory

design patterns.

Since you want to be able to create a whole family of objects that need to be of "the same kind", this can be done with **Abstract Factory** pattern.

The factory can have multiple creator methods. You can add parameters to the creator method(s) of the factory.

IShapesFactory.cs is the interface of the Abstract Factory:

```
public interface IShapesFactory
{
    Circle MakeCircle(Color color, float x, float y, float radius);
    Triangle MakeTriangle(Color color, float x, float y, float side1, float side2, float side3);

}
```

The implementation of the factory would handle passing the `Graphics` object to the shapes it creates.

ShapeFactory.cs

```
public class ShapeFactory: IShapeFactory
{
    private Graphics _graphics;

    public ShapeFactory(Graphics graphics)
    {
        _graphics = graphics;
    }

    public Circle MakeCircle(Color color, float x, float y, float radius)
    {
        // pass the Graphics object in the constructor of Circle
        return new Circle(_graphics, color, x, y, radius); 
    }

    [..other methods of the factory interface]
}
```

The factory in use:

```
IShapeFactory factory = new ShapeFactory(graphics);
var circle = factory.MakeCircle(Color.Blue, 10, 10, 20);
circle.Draw();
```