# What is the implication of naming a package, method or parameter as "Factory"?

Tags: java, frameworks, naming-conventions

This is a very basic question that doesn't seem to be asked or answered anywhere.

Sometimes we define a method and name the **parameter** as **"factory"**. Example: https://github.com/AirtestProject/Airtest/blob/c29d0462fe29db5c04cda31de1c05bcae5991061/airtest/report/js/lazyload.js

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof exports === "object") {
        module.exports = factory(root);
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], factory(root));
    } else {
        root.LazyLoad = factory(root);
    }
```

Sometimes we name the class as **SomeFactory**. Example:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d4dba1c07a1d8601f80b9e71be7853317ab0d49d/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/ActiveSessionFactory.java

```
public class ActiveSessionFactory implements SessionFactory {
```

Sometimes **methods** are named as **someFactoryMethod**. Example:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d4dba1c07a1d8601f80b9e71be7853317ab0d49d/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/ActiveSessionFactory.java

```
public synchronized ActiveSessionFactory bind(
  Predicate<Capabilities> onThis,
  SessionFactory useThis) {
Require.nonNull("Predicate", onThis);
Require.nonNull("SessionFactory", useThis);
```

Sometimes **variables** are also named as **varFactory**

```
private List<SessionFactory> factories;
```

What is the expectation around the word "factory" in these contexts? When should I name something as **"factory"**? Isn't every class essentially a blueprint or a "factory" in some way?

Not sure if this last question can be answered but are there other similar common names that classes/methods are usually named besides "factory"?

Comment: A factory instance creates instances of some other class. They're different from a simple constructor (or static factory) in that the factory implementation can vary at runtime.

Comment: @shmosel It would be great if you could explain this with an example. When I hear about a class being created dynamically I'm thinking about the generic class T being used while defining the class using angular brackets.

Comment: You should be able to Google for "factory design pattern" and get tons of results.  Or see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13029261/217324

Comment: Take the JDK's `ThreadFactory` for example. If a library wants to use threads constructed according to your specification, it would have to either duplicate all of `Thread`'s configuration options (which would make the API cumbersome and perishable) or accept thread instances (which would limit its ability to allocate threads on demand). By creating a factory, you get to define _how_ threads are created, while leaving it to the library to actually create and use them as needed.

Comment: In another scenario, you might have multiple factory implementations that are selected based on some external configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Mugen. The factory is for the factory design pattern.
[image: The Design Pattern]

Code example:

```
public abstract class TvMediaFactory {
public abstract Episode createEpisode(int number, String title);
public abstract Film createFilm(String title);
public abstract TvSeries createSeries(String title);
}
```

For the concrete classes, we can implements different behaviours.

```
 public class AnimatedFactory extends TvMediaFactory {
    @Override
    public Episode createEpisode(int number, String title) {
    return new AnimatedEpisode(number, title);
    }
    @Override
    public Film createFilm(String title) {
    return new AnimatedFilm(title);
    }
    @Override
    public TvSeries createSeries(String title) {
    return new AnimatedSeries(title);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  Marina! I think I'm understanding that factory class can produce entirely different classes even without using general class T.